# setup for recording full field sports unattended?

Tags: camera, field-recording

I'm looking for setup that I can use to record field sports (like soccer) unattended, for coaching/review purposes.

Currently I'm using a Chinese GoPro knockoff mounted to a tall fence, however the 170degree lens is not wide enough to capture the whole field because the fence is too close to the field.

I'm considering a 360 camera like the [Insta360 One X](https://store.insta360.com/product/one_x), but it seems like an inefficient use of money if I only need a single ~200 degrees lens. I'm also not going to need many of the `action cam features' like image stabilization.

Anyone have any setup or specific camera suggestions? I'd like to stay under $500.
I also considered using two Chinese GoPro knockoffs but from looking at other questions on this site it seemed like too much work to stitch them together in post.

Answer (score 1):

While not officially supported, it is not difficult to replace the lens in a GoPro knock-off. The lenses in these action cameras are using a M12 mount and can be replaced. So: you could try to replace the lens as a first step. Depending on what you are looking for in the video, details may become too small and two cameras would be a better option.

- [How To Replace GoPro Lens - DIY](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V_UIj_7cKgI)

I have done this myself with two cameras but replaced the lens with a lens that has a narrower focus. The lens costs less than 20 USD/EUR/GBP.

- [72 Degree 4.35mm 1/2.3 Inch Sensor 10MP M12 Lens](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B079ZP2PDX/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o05_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to capturing the sport only for reviewing purposes, it should be the most affordable idea to mount two cheap, wide-angle (around 20mm) camera to each goal. You shouldn't go overboard with wider lenses though, because although you see a wider range, the center point will get further away the wider your lens gets. So, buying two ~200$ gopro-knockoffs and putting them at each end of the playing-field.